# How does a spinning wheel coming into contact with rough surface, affect translational energy

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am having a bit of trouble conceptualising, the following situation.

If a wheel is spinning in air ignoring air resistance ect with an given angular velocity $\omega$ then when the wheel come into contact with rough ground so no slipping occurs, how it effect the translation energy?

In my thought process I assume that no energy is lost when it comes in to contact with the rough surface.

Comment: Hint: Friction is key here.

Comment: but would I not need a coefficient of friction, for your hint to apply

Comment: actually now thinking a little bit are you hitting that the coefficient of friction would be 1 in the case of no slipping, but I still not sure how it relates to the change in the translational energy

Comment: @james2018 No. The higher $\mu_d$ the faster the regime of pure rolling will be achieved. But a low $\mu_d$ will also achieve it, but it will take more time.

Comment: Energy in conserved when $\mu=0$ and when $\mu = \infty$. Otherwise energy is lost for the duration of slipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us look at three scenarios with increasing level of complexity.

1. **No Friction** - When the wheel comes in contact with the ground it continues to spin with $\omega$ as no torque is applied. But there is no translational motion either.
2. **Rough Surface** - Think of the wheel like a gear where the instant it comes in contact with the ground some of the rotational kinetic energy becomes translating energy. $$ \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2 = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 + \frac{1}{2} I \left( \frac{v}{R} \right)^2 $$ the solution is $$ v = R \omega \sqrt{ \frac{I}{I+m R^2} } $$
3. **Friction** - This is the most complex case. Consider the coefficient of friction $\mu$ while slipping. Consider the normal load to be applied gradually with time $N(t) = \left(\tfrac{t}{t_f}\right) W$ and corresponding friction force $F(t) = \mu N(t)$.

   The force and torque applied on the center of mass of the wheel result in linear and angular accelerations

   $$ \begin{aligned} 
     \dot{\omega} & = - \frac{R\,F(t)}{I} & \dot{v} & = \frac{F(t)}{m} \\
     \omega_f & = \omega + \int_0^{t} \dot{\omega} \,{\rm d}t = \omega - \frac{\mu R W t^2}{2 I t_f} & v & =  0 + \int_0^{t} \dot{v} \,{\rm d}t
   = \frac{\mu W t^2}{2 m t_f} 
    \end{aligned} $$

   In the end, the wheel stops slipping, and hence $v = R\, \omega_f $ which is used to find the time $t$ where slipping stops. $$ t = \sqrt{ \frac{2 m R I \omega t_f}{\mu W (I+m R^2)} } $$ and the final speed $$v = R \omega \frac{I}{I+m R^2} $$

   Finally, the ratio of final total energy to initial total energy is

   $$ \epsilon = \frac{ \frac{1}{2} m v^2 + \frac{1}{2} I \left( \frac{v}{R} \right)^2 }{ \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2 } = \frac{I}{I+m R^2} $$

Since in the limit of the third case when $\mu \rightarrow \infty$ and $t \rightarrow 0 $ the results should match case 2), leads me to believe that even with infinite friction, energy is not conserved when rolling starts. **So case 2) is incorrect due to an incorrect assumption and case 3) is the realistic answer (due to a more rigorous approach)**.

Answer (score 2):

> If a wheel is spinning in air ignoring air resistance etc with an
>   given angular velocity ω then when the wheel come into contact with
>   rough ground **so no slipping occurs**

That latter part is impossible. Initially there will be slipping because the angular deceleration $\dot{\omega}$ of the wheel is finite. The wheel cannot transit from $\omega$ to some other value *in  an instant*. Everything takes time!

Suppose there is a dynamic friction coefficient $\mu_d$ between wheel and ground, then a friction force $F_f$ arises where:

$$F_f=\mu_dF_N$$

where $F_N$ is the **Normal force** exerted by the ground on the wheel.

Assume the wheel has radius $R$ and inertial moment $I$, then the friction force exerts a torque $\tau$ about the centre of gravity:

$$\tau=F_f R$$

This frictional torque/force does three things:

1. $\tau$ reduces initial angular velocity $\omega$ acc.

$$\tau= -I\dot{\omega}=-I\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\omega$$

2. the friction force causes translational acceleration:

$$F_f=m\dot{v}=m\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}v$$

3. At some point in time:

$$v(t)=\omega(t)R$$

This is **rolling without slipping**.

Gradually translational kinetic energy increases:

$$K(t)=\frac12 mv(t)^2$$

Note even though *some* rotational kinetic energy is converted to translational kinetic energy, that conservation of energy does not apply here: the *friction force does non-conserved work*.